# limpiar tabla HTML por cada llamada GET utilizando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una aplicación MVC ASP.NET C# que consume un servicio Web Api via jQuery para obtener todos los registros de una tabla especifica y funciona bien, mi unico problema es: presiono el boton para obtener los datos y los muestra en una tabla pero si vuelvo a presionar el boton me muestra nuevamente los datos pero junto con los anteriormente recuperados, es decir, muestro dos veces los mismos datos en la tabla y si presiono una tercera vez muestro tres veces los datos.

este es mi codigo javascript, el $("#Table").empty() me funciona para no mostrar dos veces los registros pero me borra los encabezados de las columnas

```
$("#boton_de_pabletoreto").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:55987/api/Empleados",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //$("#Table").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var rows = "<tr>" +
                    "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
                    "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
                    "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
                    "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                $('#Table').append(rows);
            });
            console.log(data);
        },

        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }

    });
});
```

y el codigo HTML de la tabla

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Departamento</th>
                <th>Cargo</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

me pueden indicar como mostrar los datos solamente una vez por favor.

Comment: No te funciono `$("#Table").empty();`?

Comment: si me limpia los registros anteriores pero me borra los encabezados de cada columna

Comment: Entonces define tu `theader` y tu `tbody` y solo borras y vuleves a agregar en el body sin tocar la cabecera de la tabla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En tu html, a la tabla la segmentas en header y body. Asi:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Cargo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Y en el success del ajax, haces referencia al tbody de la tabla. Asi:

```
$('#Table > tbody').empty();
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    var rows = "<tr>" +
        "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
        "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
        "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
        "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
        "</tr>";
    $('#Table > tbody').append(rows);
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace la función `append()` es generar un elemento e insertarlo como último hijo del elemento que hayas usado en el selector. Lo que tú necesitas es que se machaque el contenido de tu tabla.

Puedes usar:

```
$('#Table').html(rows);
```

En vez de:

```
$('#Table').append(rows);
```

De esta manera la tabla será rellenada con el contenido de la variable **rows** machacando lo que la tabla tuviese dentro antes.

Comment: gracias, pero sólo me muestra el último registro.

Comment: Porque tienes que sacar el $('#Table').html(rows); del blucle .each, si no se te va a sobreescribir en cada iteración.

Answer (score 1):

0

si no deseas borrar los encabezados debes separarlos del contenido de la tabla con las etiquetas y así:

```js
$("#boton_de_pabletoreto").click(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:55987/api/Empleados",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#Table > tbody").empty();//limpia solo los registros del body
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var rows = "<tr>" +
                "<td id='id'>" + item.id + "</td>" +
                "<td id='nombres'>" + item.Nombres + "</td>" +
                "<td id='cargo'>" + item.Cargo + "</td>" +
                "<td id='dpto'>" + item.Dpto + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            $('#Table tbody').append(rows);
        });
        console.log(data);
    },

    failure: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }

});
});
```

y el codigo HTML de la tabla

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Departamento</th>
        <th>Cargo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `$('#Table').remove(rows);` antes de insertar las nuevas rows, no se si te eliminará los encabezados.

Comment: gracias, pero no me muestra nada.